# Using MapStoreConfig in a cluster raises Transition not allowed from state NOT_LOADED to LOADED exception

Tags: java, cluster-computing, hazelcast

I am attempting to use persistence for a distributed HazelCast Map. When I query the map on one node in a cluster, the other nodes report (many) instances of the following exception:

```
May 16, 2016 5:43:45 PM com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.LoadStatusOperation
SEVERE: [172.17.0.2]:5701 [dev_docker] [3.6.2] Transition not allowed from state NOT_LOADED to LOADED
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Transition not allowed from state NOT_LOADED to LOADED
    at com.hazelcast.util.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:313)
    at com.hazelcast.util.StateMachine.next(StateMachine.java:60)
    at com.hazelcast.util.StateMachine.nextOrStay(StateMachine.java:70)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.MapKeyLoader.trackLoading(MapKeyLoader.java:228)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.recordstore.DefaultRecordStore.updateLoadStatus(DefaultRecordStore.java:115)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.LoadStatusOperation.run(LoadStatusOperation.java:48)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:172)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.OperationRunnerImpl.run(OperationRunnerImpl.java:393)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.processPacket(OperationThread.java:184)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.process(OperationThread.java:137)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.doRun(OperationThread.java:124)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationexecutor.classic.OperationThread.run(OperationThread.java:99)
```

The Map is being created in each node, on request, as follows:

```
    MapConfig config = hazelcastInstance.getConfig().getMapConfig("someName");
    MapStoreConfig msConfig = config.getMapStoreConfig();
    msConfig.setEnabled(true)
        .setInitialLoadMode(MapStoreConfig.InitialLoadMode.LAZY)
        .setWriteDelaySeconds(WRITE_DELAY_SECONDS)
        .setWriteBatchSize(WRITE_BATCH_SIZE)
        .setImplementation(new RegistrationCacheStore(queueRepository));
    IMap<String, RegistrationWrapper> regMap = hazelcastInstance.getMap("someName");
    regMap.addEntryListener(new RegistrationCacheListener(queueManager, hazelcastInstance), true);
```

where `RegistrationCacheStore` is just a bridge across to the actual persistence layer.

When I invoke `values()` against the map in one node, it appears to silently work as desired (at least no exceptions are thrown in that node), but the other nodes go nuts with the exception above. Note that the underlying datastore for the map is empty at the time this is invoked, however the same behaviour pertains if there is data in the underlying table.

All the code in question works fine if there is only a single node in the cluster, which suggests I am getting something wrong with the way I'm trying to use persistence. In my case I want a distributed Map which persists through the failure/shutdown of one or all nodes in the cluster.

What is the best way to approach this?

**EDIT**
Note, this is version 3.6.2

In addition, I have just noticed that the two nodes that fail out have the message

```
INFO: [172.17.0.3]:5701 [dev_docker] [3.6.2] Partition assignments changed while executing query: TruePredicate{}
```

just prior to the (many many) exception messages (180 in fact)

Finally, I have attempted to debug this a little further by placing tracing messages in the data store code, and it appears that the data store code does not even get called. This is a very bad thing...

Comment: I've also raised this in GitHub - https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/8196